# adding Set<String> into a Java ArrayList

Tags: java

I am writing a programme that reads a word String from a file.  I am translating the string but the translator returns a Set

What I want to be able to do is to store the original word and the translated word next to each other in an ArrayList.

```
while (sc.hasNext()) {
    String entry = (sc.next());      
    System.out.println(word);
    al.add(ord);//String;
    al.add(translate(word));//Set<String>;
}
```

Now what I want to do is to access both the word and the translated word....just to test I am trying to print but this is where my code is broken.....

```
for(int i=0;i<al.size();i++){
    Object o = al.get(i);
    Object p = al.get(i);

    System.out.println("Value is "+o.toString());

    System.out.println("Value is "+p.toSet<?>());
}
```

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: it is the very last line it does not like......there is something around the  System.out.println("Value is "+p.toSet<?>()) that is wrong.  Simply will not compile

Comment: Objects have no `toSet` method... Where did you find that they did?

Comment: well this is were I need to help.....I want to get the Set<String> into an arraylist and then be able to work with it from there.  But I want the original word and the translated word in the same array list

Comment: You're going to have to post the entire class or classes, especially the translate method.

Comment: Why are you needing to store the original word along with the translation in the same list? How are you expecting to know what's been translated and what has not? You can store any object in a `List<Object>`, and when you print any object, `toString` is automatically applied so what's wrong with `System.out.println("Value is "+p);`? And note : you're getting the same index twice, so o and p would show the same thing

Comment: with translate it is a method I have been given I send it a word and it returns the translated version in a Set<String>

Comment: Why a Set of String though? I would ASSUME that translate would consume a single value and provide a single result.

Comment: @Jason not all words have singular translations

Comment: so would I but it does not......this line in the code above compiles  al.add(translate(word));//Set<String>; so it may be that the Set<String> is going into the arraylist but I have no way of telling as I cannot read it back

Comment: It compiled because you're probably using a raw list instead of `ArrayList<String>`

Comment: ok I understand you have translate method that returns all the translations of a word in a set, and then you store the main word and then the translated words in a list. now make it clear what you wants to do with these words. then people can give the idea for using better data structure for solving your problem. surely storing all the words in a single list isn't a good idea!

Comment: I am creating an ArrayList  ……………..   ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

Comment: Using raw data structures is not recommended. The angle brackets declare the type that the data structure holds

Comment: You _can't_ use an array list for this, how do you know if a word is the last translated word or the next original word? Or does the returned set always contain only 1 word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest not using a list. If you want to know which word was translated into which Set, use a Map (or a dictionary in other languages}

```
Map<String, Set<String>> translations = new HashMap<>();
while (sc.hasNext()) {
    String entry = sc.next();
    translations.put(entry, translate(entry));
}
System.out.println(translations);
```

Comment: I know.....a map would be better but I have to pass this arraylist as an argument to another piece of code so I am sort of stuck in the middle.....

Comment: Then define another method to convert the map into a list

Comment: @cosmo why does it **have** to be a list?

Answer (score 0):

**The problem**

```java
System.out.println("Value is "+p.toSet<?>());
```

This won't compile. There is no toSet<>() function for java.lang.Object.

**Another solution**

The best solution for this might be to store the original word in a Map with the translated word as the value and the original word as the key. This would only work if there are no conflicts (i.e duplicate strings).

```java
Map<String, Set<String>> words = new HashMap<>();

while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String word = sc.next();

    Set<String> translated = translate(word);

    words.put(word, translated);
}
```

Comment: Translate returns a Set, though

Comment: Why does translate return a set? Can you post the code for translate? If you think about it, if translate returns multiple words then it would be impossible to get the associated word relative to the index of the original word if there are multiple.

Comment: I'm not sure. Read the question

Comment: there are multiple words in the dictionary one on each line....I read one at a time, translate and then try and store in the arraylist….or at least this is what I am trying to do.....

Comment: Update the original post with the translate function and all other relatives classes and methods.